# インスタンス変数を参照したら，また初期化したい

Tags: ruby

例えば以下のクラスCでsayメソッドを使ったら
インスタンス変数@dはnilで初期化されています．

このメソッドは３行にわたって書いており，
もうすこしスマートに書けないかと悩んでいます．

すでに機能的には充足されていますが，
rubyらしく書くためにはどう工夫すればよいでしょうか

```
class C
  def initialize
    @d = "hello"
  end
  def say
    result = @d
    @d = nil
    result
  end
end

c = C.new
c.say #=> hello
c.say #=> nil
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`tap`を使うと良いと思います。

```
def say
  @d.tap { @d = nil }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

インスタンス変数を取り除くメソッドを使用するという手もあります。

```
def say
  remove_instance_variable(:@d) if @d
end
```

[Object#remove_instance_variable](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/class/Object.html#I_REMOVE_INSTANCE_VARIABLE)

Answer (score 2):

どうしても `@d` は文字列じゃないといけない、という制約がないのであれば、配列を使うのもアリかもです。（外から見た動きは文字列の場合と同じになります）

```
class C
  def initialize
    @d = ["hello"]
  end
  def say
    @d.pop
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class C
  def initialize
    @d = "hello"
  end

  def say
    @d
  ensure
    @d = nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class C
  def initialize
    @d = "hello"
  end

  def say
    result, @d = @d
    result
  end
end
```